# random bin picking

Tags: ros, grasp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I know that "random bin picking" is still an unsolved problem, but I would like to ask you if temptatives using ROS can be found.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265234/random-bin-picking/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The most recent information I found regarding Bin picking is Dex-Net 2.0 : http://berkeleyautomation.github.io/dex-net/

The code can be found here : https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/gqcnn

This method use [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) , I don't know if this can be called "random" but it seem promising.

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0